# Code for capturing the screenshot of live wallpaper in android 2.2

Tags: android, screenshot, live-wallpaper

I use android version 2.2 to develop.I want to capture the screenshot of live wallpaper which is the current wallpaper in the launcher. Is there the method to capture the
screenshot?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: No idea, but can I ask what you want to do with it ? I'm thinking that you want to display that image while loading your activity ?

Comment: I want to convert the screenshot to the bitmap and use the bitmap to do something.I use live wallpaper not only for the background.